# UILabel not wrapping after the text is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

[image]

I have a UI Label, and I set the `numberOfLines` to be 0 so it wraps when it needs to.

I have the text changes once in a while. Sometimes it only takes one line, but it truncates instead of wrapping when the text gets too long. The label only wraps if I refresh the table view, calling `reloadData()`.

Is there a way to automatically wrap the label without calling `reloadData()`?

Before reloading the table view:

[image]

After reloading the table view:

[image]

Comment: Do you use auto-layout for your label ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the text in a label in a table view cell, the table view does not automatically re-calculate cell sizes.

To do so, you either reload the data - as you've seen - or, execute these two lines:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

If you are updating the text in the label from *inside* your cell class, you'' want to use a delegate / protocol pattern to tell the table view controller to execute those two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the cell is the right way to let it lay itself out properly. But you don’t have to call `reloadData` (which reloads the whole table). You can do [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows), supplying the index path for only this one row. It also allows you to specify the nature of the animation you want, if any.